# valgrind misunderstanding guild

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

I'm following cLearnTheHardWay and i have just used valgrind tool but i confusing how to read it so i can fix my errors related to memory leaks if any one can explain me this couple of lines how to be read may it help making better

ex.c
    #include

```
/* Warning: This program is wrong on purpose. */

int main()
{
int age=10;
int height;

printf("I am %d years old.\n");
printf("I am %d inches tall.\n", height);

return 0;
}

I am -16777528 years old.
==15826== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15826==    at 0x4E8047E: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==15826==    by 0x4E8A388: printf (printf.c:33)
==15826==    by 0x40055E: main (ex4.c:11)
==15826== 
==15826== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==15826==    at 0x4E7F93B: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==15826==    by 0x4E835E6: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==15826==    by 0x4E8A388: printf (printf.c:33)
==15826==    by 0x40055E: main (ex4.c:11)
==15826== 
==15826== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15826==    at 0x4E7F945: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==15826==    by 0x4E835E6: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==15826==    by 0x4E8A388: printf (printf.c:33)
==15826==    by 0x40055E: main (ex4.c:11)
==15826==
```

Comment: Post the source of `ex4.c` as well.

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski  what do u mean !

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski ahh no problem brother ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that your program is using uninitialized data, and that the responsible function call is at line 11 of your `ex4.c` file. Inspecting your code should show the cause of the problem (you declare and use some variable without ever assigning it a value). Turning your compiler warning level up to the maximum should also identify the problem.

Comment: i tried to use a command --track-origins=yes and line numbers didn't been shown up .